# Can I deploy files on google cloud storage using gradle?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-storage

I am running an application on Google App Engine and I have some files in my git repository that need to be copied in the Cloud Storage to be accessed by the application.

I now copy them manually in the Cloud Storage, but I would love to find out a way to deploy them automatically together with the application when I launch

```
gradle appengineUpdate
```

or even define a new gradle task

```
gradle storageUpdate
```

Anybody had the same need and found out a possible way to do it ?

Comment: You could create a unit test that does that and make gradle execute your unit tests upon launch / package?

Comment: That's a good idea @konqi ! I don't have any gradle activated unit test yet, but I think that would make the trick. Have you ever used a similar approach ?

Comment: I did, but i use maven, so i won't be a big help with gradle (thus a comment, not an answer). Defining a separate task would be the better solution but also more effort - But you could define a task with a unit test and combine the two approaches...

Comment: My ultimate goal was to have something copying those files automatically and just forget about it... so I think I will write a solution doing that, without defining a new task. Thanks again !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of attempts, I am going to post the solution that I built, tested, perfected and that I am using in production.

First of all I created a new Java Class that handles the file upload using Storage, ACL and BlobInfo

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.builder()
                    .authCredentials(AuthCredentials.createForJson(new FileInputStream(authFile)))
                    .projectId(projectId)
                    .build()
                    .service();

List<Acl> aclList = new ArrayList<>();
aclList.add(Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), Acl.Role.READER)); // shared publicly

BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.builder(blobId)
                    .acl(aclList)
                    .build();

storage.create(blobInfo, new FileInputStream(template));
```

After that I linked it to a new gradle task calling the class

```
dependencies {

  // Google Cloud Java Client
  compile group: "com.google.cloud", name: "gcloud-java", version: "0.2.6"

}

task upload(type:JavaExec) {
  main = 'com.acme.GcsUploader'
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

//   Test Environment
  args = [
      'myProjectId', // project Id
      'myBucketName', // bucket name

      "file=${project.hasProperty("file") ? file : ""}"
  ]

}
```

Notice that in case I want to upload a single file, it will be enough call

```
gradle upload -Pfile=<filename>
```

In this way by default I will upload all the files, but in case I want to indicate a single file it can be done easily

Lat but not least, to automatically run the task it will be enough to declare a task that is already run as depending on the newly defined upload task

```
tasks.getByName('processResources').dependsOn(upload)
```